# Nginx reverse proxy doesn't work as expected

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, web-administration

I have two domains on different nginx(1.15.0) servers (**server1** *example.com* and **server2** *example.net*). I've tried to set up **server2** as a reverse proxy with *ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module* but it doesn't work as expected.
Due to my config, **subs_filter** directive should replace *example.com* to *example.net* but when I type *example.net* in browser it redirects me to *example.com*.

**nginx.conf**

```
http {
 //other settings

 .....

 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

 upstream example.com {
   server example.com;
 }

}
```

**example.net.conf**

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name example.net www.example.net;
 rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://example.net/$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl; 
  server_name example.net;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem; 
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem; 
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  location / {
    root html;
    try_files $uri @example.com;
  }

  location @example.com {
    include replace.conf;
    proxy_pass http://example.com;

    proxy_cookie_domain example.com example.net;

    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_set_header Host example.com;
    proxy_redirect http://example.com http://example.net;

  }
}
```

**replace.conf**

```
# replace direct links
subs_filter "www.example.com" "example.net" gi;
subs_filter "example.com" "example.net" gi;
```

Seems like nginx ignores **subs_filter** directive.
Could someone explain me how can I replace uri properly using ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module? Thank you for advice!

Comment: What mime type is coming back in the response?

Comment: response headers return  `text/html`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
First of all I removed upstream from **nginx.conf**:

```
upstream example.com {
  server example.com;
}
```

Then I changed following lines in **example.net.conf**:

```
  location / {
   ...
   try_files $uri @static;
  }

  location @static {
   ...
   proxy_pass https://example.com;

   ...

   ...
   ...
   proxy_redirect https://example.com https://example.net;
 }
```

All works fine except login form. Firefox works correctly but Chrome returns error 422. I suppose this is because the login form works on javascript.
Anyway thanks to all!